# html place table head at each row

Tags: php, html, odbc

I have a table with a lot columns and it has a great width so it's hard to place it at the page. So I decided to switch the rows with the columns. That's what I need:

[image]

By the default head cell setting up at the head of columns (with `<thead>` tag) how to place it at head of rows? Thanks.

**upd** The table fills with the database query result using the `odbc_fetch_array()` function. So head cells are fixed, but the value of cells varying depends on what I get from DB.

Comment: What is the markup you have had, what is the new markup, and what exactly is the problem  with it? What is this “it” that should be pöaced “at head of rows” (= ?)? And if getting data from a database is essential here, please specify what type of database is used, show the relevant code for such use, and tag the question accordingly.

Comment: Still no markup and no *actual* code that generates it, and no real problem statement (what should be placed where).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the w3c schools tutorial you can use this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<h2>Horizontal Headings:</h2>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Telephone</th>
    <th>Telephone</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>555 77 854</td>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h2>Vertical Headings:</h2>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Name:</th>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Telephone:</th>
    <td>555 77 854</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Telephone:</th>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Source:http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_headers